# KStream-KStream leftJoin not consistently emitting after window expiry

Tags: apache-kafka, left-join, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

We have a service where people can order a battery with their solar panels. As part of provisioning we try to fetch some details about the battery product, however it sometimes fails to get any data but we still want to send through the order to our CRM system.

To achieve this we are using the latest version of Kafka Streams `leftJoin`:

1. We receive an event on the `order-received` topic.
2. We filter out orders that do not contain a battery product.
3. We then wait up to 30mins for an event to come through on the `order-battery-details` topic.
4. If we dont receive that event, we want to send a new event to the `battery-order` topic with the data we do have.

This seems to be working fine when we receive both events, however it is inconsistent when we only receive the first event. Sometimes the order will come through immediately after the 30 min window, sometimes it takes several hours.

My question is, if the window has expired (ie. we failed to receive the right side of the join), what determines when the event will be sent? And what could be causing the long delay?

Here's a high level example of our service:

```kotlin
@Component
class BatteryOrderProducer {
    @Autowired
    fun buildPipeline(streamsBuilder: StreamsBuilder) {
        // listen for new orders and filter out everything except orders with a battery
        val orderReceivedReceivedStream = streamsBuilder.stream(
            "order-received",
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), JsonSerde<OrderReceivedEvent>())
        ).filter { _, order ->
            // check if the order contains a battery product
        }.peek { key, order ->
            log.info("Received order with a battery product: $key", order)
        }

        // listen for battery details events
        val batteryDetailsStream = streamsBuilder
            .stream(
                "order-battery-details",
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), JsonSerde<BatteryDetailsEvent>())
            ).peek { key, order ->
                log.info("Received battery details: $key", order)
            }

        val valueJoiner: ValueJoiner<OrderReceivedEvent, BatteryDetailsEvent, BatteryOrder> =
            ValueJoiner { orderReceived: OrderReceivedEvent, BatteryDetails: BatteryDetailsEvent? ->
                // new BatteryOrder
                if (BatteryDetails != null) {
                    // add battery details to the order if we get them
                }
                // return the BatteryOrder
            }

        // we always want to send through the battery order, even if we don't get the 2nd event.
        orderReceivedReceivedStream.leftJoin(
            batteryDetailsStream,
            valueJoiner,
            JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceAndGrace(
                Duration.ofMinutes(30),
                Duration.ofMinutes(1)
            ),
            StreamJoined.with(
                Serdes.String(),
                JsonSerde<OrderReceivedEvent>(),
                JsonSerde<BatteryDetailsEvent>()
            ).withStoreName("battery-store")
        ).peek { key, value ->
            log.info("Merged BatteryOrder", value)
        }.to(
            "battery-order",
            Produced.with(
                Serdes.String(),
                JsonSerde<BatteryOrder>()
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `leftJoin` will not trigger as long as there are no new recods. So if I have an `order-received` record with key `A` at time `t`, and then there is no new record (on either side of the join) for the next 5 hours, then there will be no output for the join for these 5 hours, because the `leftJoin` will not be triggered. In particular, `leftJoin` needs to receive a record that has a timestamp `> t + 30m`, for a `null` result to be sent.

I think to satisfy your requirements, you need to work with the more low-level Processor API: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html

In a `Processor`, you can define a `Punctuator` that runs regularly and checks if an order has been waiting for more than half an hour for details, and sends off the `null` record accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into adding a processor to see if that helps.

FYI, we are seeing joins happen, even when no new records with the same key come through after `t + 30m`. However, it's happening very inconsistently, and sometimes not at all. We have logging that rules out that it's events with the same key triggering the join. Could there also be a config element to this? We have multiple brokers too.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my answer wasn't quite correct. The join will emit the non-joined outer records (.., null) if there is _any_ new record with time `t+30m`. I updated the answer.